# JMeter basic graphs throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I using JMeter to run my load tests in Mac and have added "jpgc-graphs-basic (https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-graphs-basic) in my test plan.

Initially all the graphs were working fine and suddenly started throwing null pointer exceptions (500K exceptions for 1 Hour test) and the JMeter GUI hangs.

```
2019-10-04 12:59:25,534 ERROR o.a.j.t.ListenerNotifier: Detected problem in Listener.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.uninstallDefaults(SynthPanelUI.java:110) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.uninstallUI(BasicPanelUI.java:61) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.uninstallUI(SynthPanelUI.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.uninstallUIAndProperties(JComponent.java:681) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:658) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:153) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.graphs.GraphPanel.updateGui(GraphPanel.java:116) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.4.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.graphs.AbstractGraphPanelVisualizer.updateGui(AbstractGraphPanelVisualizer.java:222) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.4.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.graphs.AbstractGraphPanelVisualizer.updateGui(AbstractGraphPanelVisualizer.java:215) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.4.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.LatenciesOverTimeGui.add(LatenciesOverTimeGui.java:63) ~[jmeter-plugins-graphs-additional-2.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sendToVisualizer(ResultCollector.java:571) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sampleOccurred(ResultCollector.java:548) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:70) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:980) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:569) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

Tried with different version of jar files but none seems to resolve the issue.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Latencies Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LatenciesOverTime/) listener which is causing the problem is not a part of `3 Basic Graphs` bundle, you need to have [5 Additional Graphs](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-graphs-additional) in order to use this listener so my expectation is that your JMeter and Plugins bundle got corrupt somehow.

1. Install latest [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html)
2. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)
3. Open your Test Plan - the Plugins Manager should detect which plugins are being used and suggest to install them:

   [image]

   or if you prefer full control you can install them manually:

   [image]